# jQuery hide div after function is completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to display a loading image onclick on a div and hide it after loading a page in the div.

I am using the the following code but it does not hide the image after the page is loaded:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("h2").click(function(){
$("#loading").show();
$("#download").load("/api.php?id=<?php echo "$vid"; ?>");
});
});
$("#loading").hide();
</script>
<div class="subheader"><h2>Download</h2></div><div id="download"></div>
<div id="loading" class="hidden c"><img src="/images/loading.gif" alt="Please wait..." /></div>
```

How do I hide the image after loading the page?

Comment: so call it on the success method. Read the api for load

Comment: check this http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: READ THE API http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: You have the hide function out of your ready function. So it triggers too early.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load() has a callback function, in which you can put your hide()

```
$("#download").load("/api.php?id=<?php echo "$vid"; ?>", function() {
  $("#loading").hide();
});
```

Here is load() doc http://api.jquery.com/load/